# Need to get selected node text and value for radtreeview

Tags: c#, radtreeview

```
 protected void RadTreeView1_NodeClick(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Node.Level != 0)
        {
            // value of the selected child node
            string text = e.Node.Value;
        }
    }
```

here i am getting text value always null...please help me

 In radtree node click event i tried to get the node value

```
                   <telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="100px" Skin="Metro" OnNodeClick="RadTreeView1_NodeClick" AutoPostBack="true" OnClientNodeClicked="">
            <DataBindings>
                <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding Expanded="True"></telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding>
            </DataBindings>
        </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

```
   private void BindGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            DataView dv;

            string json = class.HttpGet(url + "Services/Product.svc/ProductCategorySD1");
            json = Regex.Unescape(json);
            dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '"', '.' }), typeof(DataTable));
            dv = dt.DefaultView;
            grid.DataSource = dv;
            grid.DataBind();
            RadTreeView1.DataTextField = "ProductCategoryName";
            RadTreeView1.DataFieldID = "ProductCategoryRowId";
            RadTreeView1.DataFieldParentID = "ParentProductCategoryRowId";
            RadTreeView1.DataSource = dt;

            RadTreeView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception Err)
        {

        }
        finally { }

    }
```

treebinded perfectly..........................

Comment: Please show the code where you create the node and **set** the value

Comment: In radtree node click event i tried to retrieve the value...event is perfectly firing but the text  value is always something like " "

Comment: How is RadTreeView bound to its data source?

Comment: that was already bounded by json data some thing like mentioned above

Comment: Can you show us the piece of code used to bind json data to the RadTreeView?

Comment: @Gopal Reddy You can have a look at my answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitily set the `DataValueField` property of your `RadTreeView` and *then* perform `DataBind` operation:

```
RadTree1.DataTextField = "MyTextColumn" 
// following line is absent from supplied sample in the OP
RadTree1.DataValueField = "MyValueColumn" 
RadTree1.DataFieldID = "MyID"
RadTree1.DataFieldParentID = "MyParentID"

RadTree1.DataSource = ds
RadTree1.DataBind()
```

In the sample code provided in the OP you are **only** setting `DataTextField`. My guess is if you do sth like:

```
string text = e.Node.Text;
```

you will successfully read the text of `RadTreeNode`.